# Why can not get proper dataframe with changed na_values in execl_df

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When i run this code in jupyter in na_values changed perfactly in csv_df but in excel_df in revenue column -1 is not changed to the NaN why???

https://github.com/codebasics/py/blob/master/pandas/4_read_write_to_excel/stock_data.csv
https://github.com/codebasics/py/blob/master/pandas/4_read_write_to_excel/stock_data.xlsx

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'eps':['not available', 'n.a.'],
        'people':['not available','n.a.'],
        'revenue':['not available', 'n.a.',-1],
        'price':['not available', 'n.a.']
       }
csv_df = pd.read_csv('stock_data.csv', na_values = dict)
csv_df

excel_df = pd.read_excel('stock_data.xlsx', na_values = dict)
excel_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why this is happening, but you can specify the revenue column dtype as object (string) and then covert back to numeric as a workaround. Also, in this example I changed your dict variable name to the_dict. Naming a variable dict or list is not recommended.

```
import pandas as pd

dtype =  {'revenue':'object'}

the_dict = {'eps':['not available', 'n.a.'],
        'people':['not available','n.a.'],
        'revenue':['not available', 'n.a.',-1 ],
        'price':['not available', 'n.a.']
       }

excel_df = pd.read_excel('stock_data.xlsx', dtype=dtype, na_values=the_dict)

excel_df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(excel_df['revenue'])

print(excel_df)

    tickers eps     revenue price   people
0   GOOGL   27.82   87.0    845.0   larry page
1   WMT     4.61    484.0   65.0    NaN
2   MSFT    -1.00   85.0    64.0    bill gates
3   RIL     NaN     50.0    1023.0  mukesh ambani
4   TATA    5.60    NaN     NaN     ratan tata
```